# How can I get the whole Electron back trace?

Tags: electron

When I pack my app for distribution using electron-builder and I try to run it, I get this error:

[image]

Is there a way to get the full back trace, because I cannot figure out what's wrong from just this. The error happens right away, there's no Electron/Chrome window popping up, there's no even console output from when I called the .exe:

```
C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\Dashman\clients>dist\win-unpacked\Dashman.exe

C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\Dashman\clients>
```

despite me printing "starting" from the main script. My package.json is rather simple:

```
{
  "name": "Dashman",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Dashman is the ultimate dashboard manager.",
  "author": "Flexpoint Tech Ltd",
  "main": "main/main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.3.0",
    "secp256k1": "^3.2.5",
    "eccrypto": "^1.0.3",
    "raven-js": "^3.15.0",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

The contents of the asar file, in dist\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar, include:

```
\main\main.js
```

as show by:

```
node_modules\.bin\asar l dist\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar
```

Comment: You should provide a little more context, as this isn't enough to give an answer to your question. What packager are you using, are there any errors in the dev console when running the app, what does package.json look like?

Comment: I'll add more details later, but what dev console are you referring to?

Comment: the Chrome dev console, which can be accessed via [Debugger](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/debugger/). There are also a few tools that can be used such as [Devtron](https://electron.atom.io/devtron/). You can also follow the Electron [Debugging](https://electron.atom.io/docs/guides/) Tutorials on their website. My first guess is that you are trying to create an .exe file and not using the correct params in the packager config.

Comment: Oh, it never gets to Chrome. It immediately shows that error. I even have a print on my main and it never goes out.

Comment: I found the problem. But my question is not what's broken but how to deal with those errors in Electron. Trial and error troubleshooting is very time consuming.